# How to display (STRING) result in TextArea in another class in JAVA GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

After identifying if the input guess number is higher/ lower/ correct from the MainFrame class, I want to display the string result in the textarea under FeedbackPanel class (the textarea is located in the FeedbackPanel). However after I ran the codes, the corresponding string result is not showing. How can I display the string result using FeedbackPanel class after evaluating it in the MainFrame class?

*The string result that I want to display in the Textarea in FeedbackPanel class are "Congratulations, you are correct", "Your guess is higher than the target", "Your guess is lower than the target"

FEEDBACKPANEL CLASS

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author ThatStupidCoder
 */
public class FeedbackPanel extends JPanel{
    JTextArea ta;
        
    public FeedbackPanel(){
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Feedback"));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        ta=new JTextArea(5,10);
        
        add(new JScrollPane(ta), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    
    public void appendText(String text){
        ta.append(text + "\n" + "\r");
    
    }
}
```

MAINFRAME CLASS

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    FeedbackPanel formPanel;
    InputPanel textPanel;
    public static int target;
    JTextArea ta;
    
    public MainFrame()
    {
    super("HIgher-Lower Game");
        
    formPanel=new FeedbackPanel();
    add(formPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        
        formPanel.setFormListener(new FormListener(){
            public void formEventOccurred(FormEvent e){
                int num = e.getNum();
                //int square=num*num;
                if (num == target)
                    {

                        ta.setText("Congratulations, your guess is correct!");
                        //System.out.println("Congratulations, your guess is correct!");
                    }
                else if (num > target)
                    //if guess is higher than the target
                    {
                        ta.setText("Your guess is higher than the target");
                        //System.out.println("Your guess is higher than the target");
                    }
                else if (num < target)
                    //if guess is lower than the target
                    {
                        ta.setText("Your guess is lower than the target");
                        //System.out.println("Your guess is lower than the target");
                    }
                //textPanel.appendText(Integer.toString(square));
            } 
        });
        
        textPanel=new InputPanel();
        add(textPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
                
        setSize(300,300);
    setVisible(true);
    this.pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        target = random.nextInt(100);
         
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
        new MainFrame();
            }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Any runtime error occurs?

Comment: Keep the logic outside of representation. In your case, create a class which will have a static method consuming values to estimate and returning result value

Comment: But I want it to display in the FeedbackPanel class, any tips on how to do it?